# How to convert List of string(which are already in individual json data) into a single array of json result in c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

So i have a List of string which holds Indivdual json data, because it is in c# .netCore it already holds escape character('\')  for double quotes, but in real it displays correct value that i know, but next i want an array of all these individual json result as a whole json result. what i am doing is directly Serializing this list of string as shown in below code, but it is adding extra escape charaters. is there any other better way of doing this using JsonResult or something?

```
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfIndiviualJson);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the value it store now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, `ListOfIndiviualJson` is a `List<string>` that contains strings like

```
{
    "key1": "value",
    ...
}
```

And you want to serialise it into something like:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

You can `Parse` each of the JSON strings into `JObject`, then serialise the `List<JObject>`:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfIndiviualJson.Select(JObject.Parse).ToList());
```

Obviously, if `ListOfIndiviualJson` actually contains JSON arrays instead of JSON objects, use `JArray.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have a list of json object stored as I string, but now  you want it as an array of strings.

```
string json = @"
    [ 
        { ""test1"" : ""desc1"" },
        { ""test2"" : ""desc2"" },
        { ""test3"" : ""desc3"" }
    ]";

    JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
     var _len = a.Count; // will be 3
```

Then you can convert it to a string and in json view you will see normal output.